# Something weird with css

Tags: html, css

Please look at this [site](http://planwizenew.wpengine.com/)

You can see inside the big image there three texts:

- text1
- text2
- text3

Can someone tell me why **text2** have `135px`  of `height`?

**CODE**

```
<div class="into-txt">

    <div>text1</div>
    <div>text2</div>
    <div>text3</div>

</div>

.into-txt{
    position: relative;
    top: 214px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: "almoni-400";
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be ad for your site? (Considered as spam)

Comment: What are my other options?

Comment: @Avishay28 make a fiddle with the same problem

Comment: It works good in fiddle... live site is the only place you can see this issue

Comment: @Avishay28 in this case something else is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are floating the `nav` you need to clear , otherwise it will be stay out of the flow.

Because you are using Bootstrap, just add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` just after `nav` and before `.intro-txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top: 214px;` instead of `top:214px`

```
.into-txt {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: "almoni-400";
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 214px;
}
```

**Other solution** Add this `<div class="clearfix"></div>` before `.into-txt`div or Remove `float:right` in your css from `.main-navigation` if you can.